# How to find the marginal density for X and Y given these restrictions?

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to find marginal density for X and Y. 
The function:
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\ c(x+y),  & \text{if 0<=x<=3,   1<=y<=3,   x+y>3} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

For C I got 3/49

and for the marginal density of X: 
$$\int_{3-x}^{3} f(x,y) \,dy$$

and for the marginal density of Y: 
$$\int_{3-y}^{3} f(x,y) \,dy$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly.  You missed that the support of $y$ must not be below $1$.  That is: for any $x$ then $y\in\big[\max\{1,3-x\};\, 3\big]$

$$\begin{align}
1 & = c\;\int_1^3\int_{3-y}^3 x+y\operatorname d x\operatorname d y & \therefore c=3/49
\\[2ex]
f_Y(y) & = {\chi}_{y\in[1;3]}\;\int_{3-y}^3 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y
\\[2ex]
f_X(x) & = {\chi}_{x\in[0;3]}\;\int_{\max(1,3-x)}^3 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
 & = {\chi}_{x\in[0;2]}\;\int_{3-x}^3 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y
+ {\chi}_{x\in(2;3]}\;\int_{1}^3 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y
\end{align}$$